# Vue.js - Element UI - Select remote search debounce - Possible issue memory Usage

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to use a `select` with `remote search` using `vue.js-2.3` and `element-ui` library. [Documentation here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select)

In the example they gave, they triggered the remote search each time user enters a value. I would like to `debounce` this. Also, I would like to make the field `clearable`.

#### Issue

With the fiddle, the field is not clearable and the first value picked always came back.
In my real code, I feel like too much memory is used. If the `vue-devtools` is opened and if I'm selected something, my browser crashes.

#### Minimal reproduction code

https://jsfiddle.net/24wv1hz7/

```
<div id="app">
  <el-form class="formClientPage" ref="form" label-width="120px" label-position="top">
    <el-form-item label="Store" required>
      <el-select v-model="storePicked" filterable clearable :filter-method="setStoreInput" placeholder="Select">
        <el-option v-for="store in computedStoreList" :key="store.id" :label="store.store" :value="store.id">
          <span style="float: left">{{ store.store }}</span>
          <span style="float: right; color: #8492a6; font-size: 13px">{{store.interal_id}}</span>
        </el-option>
      </el-select>
    </el-form-item>
  </el-form>
</div>


var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        storePicked: false,
        storeSearchValue: '',
        storeList: [],
        ajaxList: [........],
      }
    },
    computed: {
     computedStoreList () {
        if (this.storeList) {
          return this.storeList.filter(store => {
            return store.store.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.storeSearchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1 || store.interal_id.toString().indexOf(this.storeSearchValue) > -1;
          })
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      setStoreInput: _.debounce(function (queryStore) { this.storeSearchValue = queryStore; }, 250)
    },
    mounted () {
        const _this = this;
     setTimeout(() => {_this.storeList = _this.ajaxList}, 1000);
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

### Questions

What is wrong with the jsfiddle? Am I using the functionnalty in the right way ? (computed property and so on)[image]